# What is the best way to use view controllers in storyboards for an instructional app to not overload the memory?

Tags: swift, xcode, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to make an instructional app where the user is told to do something specific to install some hardware. Each view tells them a step and when they press a button, the view provides the next step to do. I want to know what is the best way to make an instructional app where different views will be needed but want to take into account memory. Should I just make a new view controller in the storyboard for each step with a segue button or is there a better way.

I started to make a segue for each view with its own view controller. So Step 1 says hello with a next button, user presses next and it segues into a new view controller with the next step and a button for the following step but I just realized I am going to end up with about 20 views in my stack. My question is more of what is the proper way of doing this. Is it okay to have so many view controllers in my story board using segues since each view only has images, labels, and buttons? Or are there more appropriate ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

For your task, just use one ViewController, with a container view, where you can embed other ViewControllers, when needed.
[Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)